# read/write string over tcp network stream

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have been sending binary data between applications lots of times over TCP sockets but never before using strings. Bumbed into an issue intending to do so. Here is what I got:

```
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("localhost", port);

        //Connects fine
        NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);

        //The code moves on but nothing seems to be sent unless I do
        //a sw.Close() after this line. That would however close the  
        //ns and prevent me from reading the response further down
        sw.Write("hello");

        //I am using a stream reader with ReadToEnd() on the tcpListener
        //which never receives the string from this piece of code

        //Since the above never actually send I get stuck here
        string response = new StreamReader(ns).ReadToEnd();

        sw.Close();
        tcpClient.Close();
```

How do I send the string without closing the network stream? ns.Flush() is what I would be looking for really.

Comment: A word about flushing. From the NetworkStream documentation, ns.Flush() does nothing, and sw.Flush() is reserved for future use...so I guess flushing in this case does nothing at all.

Comment: That's not correct (wether that is a mistake in the doc or not). ns.Flush() is reserved for future use but not sw.Flush(). If I comment out the sw.Flush(), it fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an `sw.Flush()` , that ought to work. A `WriteLine()` might have done it too.

But when the other side does a ReadLine() then you have to make sure you end with newline. Try WriteLine() instead of Write().

And be careful about closing a StreamReader/Writer, they also close their underlying streams.

Comment: I tried adding the sw.Flush() after sw.Write() but it still doesn't seem to send anything.

Comment: @bluevoo Are you sure nothing is send (vs no reaction) ?  If the other side does a ReadLine() then you're missing a newline. Try WriteLine() instead of Write().

Answer (score 1):

There's a `StreamWriter.Flush()`. When you get done with sending you message, just do `sw.Flush()`. However, since buffer sizes are fairly large (upto a couple KB), the correct way is to only `Flush()` just before you wait for a response. That way several calls to `.Write()` can be bundled into a single packet and sent down the wire at the same time.

Comment: tried adding the sw.Flush() after sw.Write() but it still doesn't seem to send anything.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the [AutoFlush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx) property on the StreamWriter to true.

Comment: That would flush after every single write...not very good for performance.